# How to merge connected lines with same direction (PostGis)

Tags: postgis, sql

I am looking for a way to join all lines that are connected,  have the same direction, i.e. start point of one is end point of the other, and share some common attributes. In fact, I want to connect oneway streets having an common start/end point and the same oneway direction. I found a way to identify pairs of lines that fulfill these condition:

```
select a.osm_id, a.name,a.oneway,
       b.osm_id, b.name,b.oneway, from planet_osm_line a, planet_osm_line b 
   WHERE (st_startpoint(a.way)=st_endpoint(b.way) or st_endpoint(a.way)=st_startpoint(b.way))
         and a.oneway=b.oneway ;
```

I am now looking for a way to merge the geometries of these lines.

Comment: That query will give you doubles. Since you're doing a self-join you'll get pairs (road1,road2) and (road2,road1).

Comment: Simplifying the where condition to `WHERE st_startpoint(a.way)=st_endpoint(b.way)` solves this issue

Comment: You can merge the linestrings with ST_LineMerge(a.way, b.way), but you'll have to insert this new geometry into a new table. And you'll have to decid what to do with the 'name' and 'osm_id' columns...

Comment: ST_LineMerge(st_union(a.way, b.way)) works. However, I thought more about an aggregate query with a group clause. In addition, the query is extremely slow, I suppose due to the fact that the extremities of all lines are compared against each other.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, based on a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION joinOneways() RETURNS SETOF planet_osm_line AS
   $BODY$
   DECLARE a record;
   DECLARE b record;
   DECLARE c integer;    
   BEGIN
      drop table if exists pool;
      create table pool as select * from planet_osm_line where coalesce(oneway,'') not in ('','no');
      LOOP
         select count(*) from pool into c;
         IF c = 0 THEN
            RETURN;
         END IF;
         FOR a IN EXECUTE 'select * from pool  order by st_length(way) DESC;'
         LOOP
            FOR b IN SELECT *  FROM pool  order by st_length(way) DESC
            LOOP
               IF st_touches(a.way,b.way) AND (st_startpoint(a.way)=st_endpoint(b.way)  or st_startpoint(b.way)=st_endpoint(a.way))
                  AND a.name=b.name THEN
                  a.way = st_linemerge(st_union(a.way,b.way));
                  EXECUTE 'delete from pool where osm_id=$1' USING b.osm_id;
               END IF;            
            END LOOP;
            EXECUTE 'delete from pool where pool.osm_id=$1' USING a.osm_id;
            RETURN NEXT a; 
            EXIT;
         END LOOP;
      END LOOP;
      RETURN;
   END
   $BODY$
   LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

   CREATE TABLE oneways as select * from joinOneways();
```

The function is not perfect as it is not looking for the longest contiguous oneway path. It may be not very performant neither .